# How to put comment when use sendrawtransaction in bitcoincore?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I use [sendrawtransaction](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/rawtransactions/sendrawtransaction/) to submitt my transaction and I want to put comment or comment-to in transaction like [sendtoaddress](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/sendtoaddress/) fields that store in the wallet and not sent with transactions. I think the `"data": "hex"` field in [createrawtransaction](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/rawtransactions/createrawtransaction/) is for this, but I can not use that.

I use the following list as recipients field in createrawtransaction, but I get error: ***bitcoinrpc.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -8: Invalid parameter, key-value pair must contain exactly one key***

```
 [{'mowMh2bocyV97NUP9vqVsuCPcJ2XhJUuoH': Decimal('0.000123'),
 '2NAJPzU1pVTcNABNrdrD336eRWRrbKBBuSe': Decimal('0.03149347')},
 {'data': 'happy birthday'}]
```

How to use that? Is there any good idea to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is meant for OP_RETURN outputs.

You cannot add comments using `sendrawtransaction`.

Comment: Do you have any idea to put comment?

Comment: Use sendtoaddress, or keep a map of `txid`:`comment` in an outside database.